Predict total unique observations based on sample - R
I have a set of data that contains N unique elements, these elements may be duplicated any number of times to give X total elements.
The values of N and X are unknown.
I have a sample of this data, and have counted the total sample size, and total unique elements within the sample.
To get an impression of the structure of my sample, I have taken repeated sub-samples at a range of sample sizes, with no replacement, and counted the unique elements.
Plotted here:

(Red = total sample, black = downsamples. Each of the visible black points is actually 20 replicates).
From this, I want to fit a curve in R that extends beyond the observed values of x to predict the maximum value of y (eg: the total number of unique elements in the dataset, N).
Total Elements in Sample: 185718411
Total Unique Elements within the Sample: 51588754
Downsampled data:
x=c(1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 
1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 
1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 1e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 
2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 
2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 
2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 
5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 
5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 
7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 
7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 
7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 7.5e+07, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 
1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 
1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 
1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 
1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 
1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.25e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 
1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 
1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 
1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.5e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 
1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 
1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 1.75e+08, 
1.75e+08, 1.75e+08)
y=c(8879407L, 8882853L, 
8879146L, 8879963L, 8879973L, 8877565L, 8879535L, 8879441L, 8881377L, 
8880961L, 8880186L, 8879063L, 8881647L, 8879511L, 8881403L, 8878382L, 
8879544L, 8881002L, 8880604L, 8880240L, 18927193L, 18924435L, 
18923731L, 18920494L, 18923974L, 18923199L, 18923360L, 18923648L, 
18923131L, 18922984L, 18926592L, 18924276L, 18923680L, 18923344L, 
18926252L, 18921600L, 18924428L, 18928711L, 18925935L, 18922126L, 
30157610L, 30155501L, 30158640L, 30159612L, 30158025L, 30157679L, 
30154834L, 30159222L, 30160493L, 30157565L, 30158045L, 30157807L, 
30155821L, 30155840L, 30158622L, 30159742L, 30161088L, 30158046L, 
30159089L, 30155885L, 37409984L, 37400952L, 37402514L, 37408682L, 
37404248L, 37403547L, 37401649L, 37407739L, 37405915L, 37407328L, 
37402003L, 37408206L, 37398749L, 37406762L, 37401890L, 37406383L, 
37404693L, 37409054L, 37403259L, 37405316L, 42387997L, 42386810L, 
42386963L, 42390976L, 42390837L, 42387186L, 42387391L, 42385265L, 
42383010L, 42392749L, 42390451L, 42390822L, 42389636L, 42389803L, 
42385593L, 42390989L, 42386302L, 42389008L, 42390049L, 42386454L, 
45991832L, 45992758L, 45991351L, 45993242L, 45993277L, 45990663L, 
45992366L, 45992018L, 45994867L, 45996211L, 45992212L, 45991838L, 
45991638L, 45992517L, 45993411L, 45993444L, 45992878L, 45993934L, 
45993354L, 45993045L, 48707677L, 48710261L, 48705408L, 48705354L, 
48706640L, 48708658L, 48708765L, 48708926L, 48707986L, 48709516L, 
48705780L, 48708451L, 48707766L, 48711356L, 48708200L, 48707612L, 
48708961L, 48707509L, 48708770L, 48706288L, 50821205L, 50820451L, 
50819444L, 50821245L, 50821327L, 50820153L, 50819789L, 50821493L, 
50821043L, 50819115L, 50821689L, 50821538L, 50821014L, 50819974L, 
50821665L, 50819515L, 50820771L, 50819985L, 50820110L, 50819491L, 
51588754L)

I think the shape of the curve fits an asymptotic regression, and I've had a look at various methods of fitting, but I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for.
I know that down-sampling a sample isn't equivalent to taking repeated samples - but this is all I have access to. So I have to work on the (valid) assumption that the sample is representative of the dataset as a whole, given its size and the consistency of the replicates.
I want to repeat this for many different datasets, so looking for a method that can be applied consistently.
Thanks!

If you want to estimate the maximum number of unique elements, in theory you could fit any kind of asymptotic function. However, think carefully about whether you feel confident that there is a true maximum.
This is a similar problem to the Species Discovery Curve , where as more samples are taken, more different species are discovered. This is usually fit to a logarithmic function, where the rate of discovery slows as sampling effort increases, but there is no theoretical maximum.

Just adding this in case anyone is looking for a solution. For my purposes, I found the following curve fitting approach to work:
xy.frame <- data.frame(x, y)

fit <- nls(y ~ Vm * x/(K + x), 
    data = xy.frame, 
    start = list(K = max(xy.frame$x), Vm = max(xy.frame$y)))


It would be amazing to understand a bit more the setup you are dealing with.
If X is a unique identifier and N is a category it belongs to (So we have 'many times' the same category N, but we CAN identify the different individuals when sampling them;
My approach would be to capture-recapture. With this we could approximate X, based on the observed N. But still, I cannot think on how this helps with finding the theoretical maximum of new categories or species. Related to the comment of Jacob, there may not be a theoretical maximum, but finding new species is just more costly.
A different approach I could try is to find the distribution of every item in N. So, in case we are dealing only with words, and we cannot identify the words, finding the maximum amount of words will be tough, most likely impossible, but we can indeed find the expected probability of each word. There may be words that appear very rarely in the texts. There may be words that appear most of the time. If you consider each of the words as N and the whole text as X, still you cannot do anything about the asymptotic distribution of N, there will always be a new word no one ever thought about... (but you could try the asymptotic distribution of the proportion as the sample size grows; N_i/X)
